# Top_n return both max and min value - R

Tags: r, dplyr, top-n

is it possible for the top_n() command to return both max and min value at the same time?

Using the example from the reference page https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html

I tried the following

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1)) 
df %>% top_n(c(1,-1)) ## returns an error

df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1)) 
df %>% top_n(1) %>%  top_n(-1) ## returns only max value
```

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use `summarise(max_x = max(x), min_x = min(x))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really involving `top_n()`, but you can try:

```
df %>%
 arrange(x) %>%
 slice(c(1, n()))

   x
1  1
2 10
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 slice(which(x == max(x) | x == min(x))) %>%
 distinct()
```

Or (provided by @Gregor):

```
df %>%
 slice(c(which.min(x), which.max(x)))
```

Or using `filter()`:

```
df %>%
 filter(x %in% range(x) & !duplicated(x))
```

Comment: Similar, `df %>% slice(which.max(x), which.min(x))` means you don't need the `distinct`. (Though it doesn't give you the option of omitting the `distinct`)

Comment: @Gregor - reinstate Monica that's really neat, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Idea similar to @Jakub's answer with `purrr::map_dfr`

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr and purrrr for map_dfr

df %>% 
  map_dfr(c(1, -1), top_n, wt = x, x = .)
#    x
# 1 10
# 2  1
# 3  1
# 4  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `top_n` where we pass a logical vector based that returns TRUE for min/max using `range` and then get the `distinct` rows as there are ties for range i.e duplicate elements are present

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   top_n(x %in% range(x), 1) %>%
   distinct
#   x
#1 10
#2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @tmfmnk's answer. If you want to use top_n function, you can do this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1))

bind_rows(
  df %>% top_n(1),
  df %>% top_n(-1)
)

# this solution addresses the specification in comments
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(min = min(x),
            max = max(x),
            average = mean(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!

In fact, my data set was a bit more complicte, such that 

df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 34, 12, 18, 19, 8), 
                 y = sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), 12, replace = T))

df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(average = mean(x))

I wanted to obtain both max and mean average and a proper label to which group it belongsa and it works fine with your solution

Comment: It can be also changed slightly with `pipeR` i.e. `df %>>% (~ mx = top_n(., 1)) %>% top_n(-1) %>% bind_rows(mx, .)`

Comment: I tried to provide you with an alternative solution that would allow you to have min, max and average and also the label. You can do a row transformation with gather if you want.